# click only one random button from the true condition response jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, click

I'm a newbie in jquery/javascript and i need some help!
I'm trying to click only one button from the true condition response, but all the time the script will click on all the buttons of the true condition response.. I don't know how to solve this.

```
$(".enemy-box").each(function(index) {
    var pret = Number($(this).find('.attack-price').text().replace(/,/g, '').split('$')[1]);
    var name = $(this).find('.enemy-name').text().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    var x = $(this).find(document.getElementsByClassName("btn attack-btn")); // this will click on all the true conditions buttons


    /* I have tried with this but stil not working. the script will click on all the true conditions buttons!
    var len  = $(this).find(document.getElementsByClassName("btn attack-btn")).length;
    var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) + 0;
    var x = $(this).find(document.getElementsByClassName("btn attack-btn")).eq(random);    
    */

    if (name.indexOf("Test") == -1 && pret <= 39.99 ) {
        x.click();
    }

});
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Show your HTML part.

Comment: Your question is not clear post complete js with html

Comment: You're already using `$(this).find(className)` twice, why would you suddenly go back to selecting multiple elements using `getElementsByClassName()`? You are *already* looping over all `.enemy-box` elements. Or do you actually have multiple `.attack-btn`s per `enemy-box`? Show your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $(this).find(document.getElementsByClassName("btn attack-btn")); with $(this).find('.attack-btn:first);.

getElementByClassName is unnecessary when using jQuery. :first will return only the first occurrence of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are passing the document as context to the find() function. And, since you are using jQuery, you don't need to use JS method. Simply pass the selector to the method find().

You can do that either by

```
var x = $(this).find('btn.attack-btn:first');
```

or

```
var x = $(this).find($('btn.attack-btn').eq(0));
```